# AWK command print say 1st 5th and rest columns

Tags: awk

Using Awk command I want to print 1st, 3rd, 5th to last column

Sample input file contains:

```
1st line
    05/05/2015 14:10:40 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M
2nd line
    05/05/2015 14:11:21 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M
3rd line
    05/05/2015 14:14:21 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M
```

1st column i.e. 05/05/2015 
3rd i.e. [739] 
and I want to print all the columns starting from 5 to end
i.e. No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M

But I want to compare duplicates of strings in column 5th with every line

Expected output should be:

```
05/05/2015 [739]: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M
```

Because considering the the 5th column of 1st line i.e. "No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE^M" with other 2 lines there should be only one

For printing columns as mentioned above this code words awk -F" " '{print $1,$3;for (i=5; i<=NR; i++) print $i }' $file

```
for i in $*
 do
  while read line
   do
     var1=`awk -F" " '{print $1}' $line`
     var2=`awk -F" " '{print $3}' $line`
     var3=`awk -F" " '{for (i=5; i<=NR; i++) print $i }' $line`
     echo "$var1 $var2 $var3"
   done
 done
```

Comment: what will you do when you find a duplicate string between lines. **Please** edit your question to include your sample output. Also, your current solution is very "expensive" process (and code) wise. If I understand your question (without seeing your required output), I'm pretty sure you can write it with only 1 awk script for the whole process. Show us your required output and we can probably help. Good luck!

Comment: Your "Expected output" includes the 2nd and 4th fields from the input. Edit it to match what you say you want output or change the text of what you say you want output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
05/05/2015 14:10:40 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 14:10:40 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 14:11:21 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 14:11:21 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 14:14:21 [739]: indic.cxx.400: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 14:14:22 [739]: indic.cxx.400: Other Message
05/05/2015 14:14:23 [739]: indic.cxx.400: Something Else
05/05/2015 14:14:24 [739]: indic.cxx.400: Something Else
```

To print fields 1, 3, and 5 to end on each line unless fields 5 to end are the same as on the previous line:

```
$ awk '{f="";for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) f=f" "$i;} f!=last{print $1,$3,f;} {last=f;}' file
05/05/2015 [739]:  No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 [739]:  Other Message
05/05/2015 [739]:  Something Else
```

#### How it works

This script uses two variables.  `f` has the fields from 5 to the end for the current line.  `last` has the same fields from the previous line.

- `f=""; for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) f=f" "$i;`

  Every time that we start a new line, this sets the string variable `f` to all the fields from 5 to the end.
- `f!=last {print $1,$3,f;}`

  If the current value of `f` is not the same as the `last`, that is, `f!=last`, then print the selected fields from the line.

  If you want to change the output format, then just adjust the print statement here.
- `last=f;`

  As the last thing to do before we go to the next line, update the variable `last` to the current line's `f`.

Comment: It is working perfectly, can you give a brief explaination about the code you wrote. Thanks

Comment: @AnuragDeb Very good.  I added an explanation.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: The above code works if the lines are sorted i.e. if duplicacy is in consecutive lines. See the above example given by @John1024.
but if you want to use the code for removing duplicacy in alternate line also
Use sort ex:  
    <code>
    sort -k4,10 file
    </code>

It will sort based on 4th to 10th column and after that if below code is ran, it will work for alternate line duplicacy also.

awk '{f="";for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) f=f" "$i;} f!=last{print $1,$3,f;} {last=f;}' file

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample input file posted by @John1024 with gawk:

```
$ awk '{key=gensub(/^(\S+\s+){4}/,"","")} !seen[key]++{print $1, $3, key}' file
05/05/2015 [739]: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 [739]: Other Message
05/05/2015 [739]: Something Else
```

and any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{key=$0; sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}/,"",key)} !seen[key]++{print $1, $3, key}' file
05/05/2015 [739]: No more free context, TYPE=SINGLE
05/05/2015 [739]: Other Message
05/05/2015 [739]: Something Else
```